# Issues using simplePagination jQuery plugin with tablesorter widget

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm using the simplePagination jQuery plugin to perform the pagination and table sorter for sorting and filtering the inputs. The reason i chose 'simplePagination' over 'tablesorter pager' as i wanted to perform similar functionality as the simplePagination perform for my project.
However I'm seeing some issues/clashes while using tablesorter widget and simplePagination plugin. 
Issues:
1) im unable to display the required records per page (i.e: 10 records on a page) anymore.
2) im unable to filter the items when i type in the search box.

below is my initialization for both both plugins:

tablesorter: JS

```
$("#table").tablesorter({
     widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
     widgetOptions : {
        filter_columnFilters: false
}
```

simplePagination:Js

```
perPage = 10;
$("#pagination").pagination({
    items: 20,
    itemsOnPage: perPage,
    onPageClick: function(pageNumber) { 
        var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
        var showTo = showFrom + perPage;
        items.hide().slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
    },
});
```

has anyone encountered similar situation before..Any ideas how can it be resolved??
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use simplePagination, you'll need to use it along side the pager plugin or widget. [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/yfwwzvL8/1/) using the pager widget:

```
$(function () {
    var perPage = 10,
        $table = $('table');
    $table.tablesorter({
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter', 'pager'],
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_columnFilters: false,
            pager_size: perPage
        },
        initialized: function (table) {
            /* 
            Using http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/
            along with the pager widget
            */
            var pager = table.config.pager;
            $("#pagination").pagination({
                cssStyle: 'compact-theme',
                items: pager.totalRows,
                itemsOnPage: pager.size,
                onPageClick: function (pageNumber) {
                    $table.trigger('pageSet', pageNumber);
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

I'm not sure what to tell you about the filtering.. when the `filter_columnFilters` option set to `false` there is no way to set the filter. Or no way to interact with the filter widget was shared in the question. Do you have an external input?

Comment: Also, I don't know if you've see [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/beta-testing/example-pager-custom-controls.html) using the custom pager controls extension.

Comment: thanks a lott for the explanation, i got it working now..as for filter, yes im using external input, but looks like the issue was i was using simplePagination alone with tablesorter, i followed ur approach and my issue with the filtering seems to be ok now..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, though im not sure if its the best way or not, but just a workaround, will figure something better.
I used the tablesorter-pager plugin to determine the records on a page:

```
$("#table").tablesorterPager({
    page: 0,
    size: 10,    
});
```

and it worked for me, definitely this is not the best approach, but for now, its fine!!:)